# HTTP connection parsing fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to call `connect()` function inside `parse_ip()` which would search for input IP through the webpage to find a match.
`Connect` function is called for each element of list `THREAT`.
Here is my code:

```
def connect(url):
    sessions = requests.Session()
    print "Connecting with", url
    try:
        r = sessions.get(url,
                        headers = create_basic_headers(),
                        proxies = {'http': HTTP_PROXY, 'https': HTTPS_PROXY})
        return r
    except:
        sys.stdout.write('[!] Could not connect to: %s\n' % url)

def parse(ip):
    counter = 0
    ioc_list = []
    for filename, source in THREAT.iteritems():
        c = connect(source)
        for line in c:
            if line.startswith("/") or line.startswith('\n') or line.startswith("#"):
                pass
            else:
                counter += 1
                d = 0
                while d < len(ip):
                    if ip[d] in line:
                        print ip[d], source

                    d +=1
```

On running the script, the parsing page fails to connect and atlast I get the following error:

> [!] Could not connect to: http://...
>       for line in c: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Can anyone help me out in figuring what is going wrong in this.

Comment: Why don't you try catching and then printing the exception in `connect()`?

Comment: Temporarily remove the try/except block to show the stack trace, which is more helpful than what you have there. When you finally figure it out, do catch a specific exception and handle it. Do not catch all exceptions the way you currently doing: it makes it hard to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` is failing to establish a connection to the server. An exception is raised which is then handled in the *bare* except clause. No information about the exception is displayed, so it is hard to diagnose the actual connection problem.

After the exception `connect()` returns `None` to the caller, which then tries to iterate over it. This is what causes the `TypeError`.

Why don't you try printing the exception?

```
def connect(url):
    sessions = requests.Session()
    print "Connecting with", url
    try:
        r = sessions.get(url,
                        headers = create_basic_headers(),
                        proxies = {'http': HTTP_PROXY, 'https': HTTPS_PROXY})
        return r
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
        sys.stdout.write('[!] Could not connect to: %s\n' % url)
        sys.stdout.write('Exception: %s' % exc)
```

Hopefully that will show you why the connection is failing.

Following that, you need to check the return value of `connect()` in `parse()`. Something like:

```
c = connect(source)
if c is not None:
    for line in c:
        ....
```

Alternatively you could re-raise the exception in `connect()` and let `parse()` deal with it.

Comment: Thanks Ahawke. catching detailed exception helped me figure out that the connection was getting refused due to firewall settings. Mpdifying them helped get things working. Thanks!

Comment: @abhinavsingh: good to hear. Take the advice regarding bare `except:` statements. As you have seen they make debugging difficult.